# Can't type characters inside a function using new google Apps script editor (but can delete)

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, ide

I'm sure this is a crazily easy thing to solve, and I'm doing something really basic wrong but I can't figure it out. It's also a tricky one to explain.

This is an issue only in the new google apps script environment. Switching to the legacy editor is fine.

I can't type new characters (letters, numbers, symbols, spacebar etc) inside certain parts of existing functions. But I can delete characters or add new line using the return key.
BUT I can type in other places in the same function. It's bizarre.
[image]
I've attached an image illustrating this for one of the functions. It's not just happening in that function though, it's happening on a few functions, with no apparent pattern.

I'm using Chrome on Mac OS 10.14.6

I'm sure I'm being silly. I've just been switching back to the legacy editor for months because I couldn't find anyone with the same problem and I felt too stupid to ask!

EDIT: I've just tried this using Safari and everything is fine. I guess it's a Chrome bug. However this has been happening on Chrome for months now and I've had plenty of updates. :/

Comment: Any errors, when attempting to type, logged in Browser devtools console logs? Tried clearing app data, cache etc? Any addon interfering?

Comment: Try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled. If that fix the problem, then is very likely that there an extension is causing the problem.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you. Thanks to your help I've narrowed it down to a clash with a particular chrome extension called Magical Text Expander. Makes sense that it would interfere with typing, though why its only on certain lines I haven't a clue!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Ruben. This issue was being caused by a clash with a Chrome extension called Magical - Text Expansion (Chrome Extension identifier iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp).

Disabling this plugin and then restarting the Chrome window fixed the issue.

I'm pretty inexperienced in this, I will know to look for extension issues in future.

Thanks again.